# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException - is the Error

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am new to Java Spring Boot.I am creating a sample project for learning.I am creating a application.in Which the API can add Book,get all the books,Get book depending on Id,Delete the book depending on Id and Update Book.
When i Create Basic API and run the Error is getting Prompted
>

```
Error creating bean with name 'booksController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bookService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'booksRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'booksRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.book.Books.model.Book
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.books.Books.BooksApplication.main(BooksApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
```

My BooksController.java

```
package com.books.Books.controller;
import com.book.Books.model.*;
import com.books.Books.repository.BooksRepository;
import com.books.Books.service.BooksService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
@RestController

public class BooksController {

@Autowired
BooksService bookService;


@GetMapping("/books/getall")
public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
    return bookService.getBook();
}
//Get a Single Book
@GetMapping("/book/{id}")
public Optional<Book> getBookById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long 
bookId) {
    return bookService.findBookId(bookId);

}

}
```

My BooksService.java

```
 package com.books.Books.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import com.book.Books.model.Book;

public interface BooksService {

public List<Book> getBook();
public Optional<Book> findBookId(Long Id);
}
```

My BookServiceimpl.java

```
package com.books.Books.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.book.Books.model.Book;
import com.books.Books.repository.BooksRepository;

@Service
public class BookServiceImpl implements BooksService {

@Autowired
BooksRepository booksRepository;

@Override
public List<Book> getBook() {
    return booksRepository.findAll();

}@Override
public Optional<Book> findBookId(Long Id){

    return booksRepository.findById(Id);
}




}
```

My pom.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.books</groupId>
<artifactId>Books</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Books</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF- 
   8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     </dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Thank You

Comment: have you implemented `bookServiceImpl`?

Comment: Your app is not detecting `Book` class as a `@Entity`. Check `Book` class annotations and `@ComponentScan` annotation.

Comment: Please add the BookService implementation class to clarify. This exception might be due to a misconfiguration in that class. i.e. Not having @Service annotation on the class or lack of any injected dependency.

Comment: I have added the code @akarimin

Comment: what should i do to rectify it @MladenSavić

Comment: yes i have implemented @dehasi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added

`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.webapp.example.repository.**")`

on Spring boot main class ? Please specify your project's repository directory path.

Also adding

`@ComponentScan("com.webapp.example.domain")`

on Spring boot main class could help Spring to find `@Entity` annotated domain objects.

Another solution could be decorating spring boot main class with

`@EntityScan("com.webapp.example.domain")`

to force Spring to look for `@Entity`'s in specified directory.